# 'ObjectContext' does not contain a definition for 'Entry' and no extension method 'Entry'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4.1

I upgraded my `EntityModel` to version `4.3` using `NuGet`.

Now i want to change my `EntityObject.State`, but it cant find the `.Entry()` method.

The current state is `Deleted`.

This is what i want to do:

`someObjectContext.Entry(someEntityObject).State = EntityState.Unchanged;`

The referances to EntityFramework and EntityFramework.Extended are added.

So, what am i missing?

**EDIT**

My `NuGet` output:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 4.3.1
'EntityFramework 4.3.1' already installed.
Data already has a reference to 'EntityFramework 4.3.1'.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're using [`ObjectContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx), which does not have the `Entry` method. You'd have to use [`DbContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), which is a wrapper around `ObjectContext` with additional methods, added in EF <strike>4.3</strike> 4.1(correction thanks to Slauma) as far as I remember - also there's a way to extract the `ObjectContext` from `DbContext` when needed:

```
ObjectContext context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)yourDbContext).ObjectContext;
```

Here's the other way around:

```
DbContext context = new DbContext(yourObjectContext, true); //or false, depends what you want
```

Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696505%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to the constructor.

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor Thanks for the help. Work perfect! =)