# ObjectContext not retrieving recent changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, telerik-grid

This code works fine, However, if I run execute a storedprocedure in my unit of work class (or any update, delete, add operation),  I'm still getting original the data. Actually, I have already a solution(posted below in controller) but Im sure this is not the most elegant way, I hope someone can help me refactor the code. please help.  Thanks

My unit of work

```
 public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
 {
   private readonly ObjectContext _context;
   private BookRepository _books;

    public UnitOfWork(ObjectContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Context was not supplied");
        }

        _context = context;
    }

    public IRepository<Book> Books
    {
        get
        {
            if (_books== null)
            {
                _books= new BookRepository (_context);
            }

            return _books;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateAuthor(int id)
    {
        _context.ExecuteStoreCommand("sp_UpdateAuthor @param1", 
            new SqlParameter("param1", id));
     }

     public void Commit()
    {           
       _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Book Repository

```
public class BookRepository : Repository<Book>
{
    public BookRepository (ObjectContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    public override Machine GetById(object id)
    {
        return _objectSet.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id== (int)id);
    }
}
```

Generic Repository

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : class, IAuditEntity
{
    protected IObjectSet<T> _objectSet;

    public Repository(ObjectContext context)
    {
        _objectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }

    public abstract T GetById(object id);

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _objectSet;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    {
        return _objectSet.Where(filter);
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _objectSet.AddObject(entity);
    }

    public void Remove(T entity)
    {            
        _objectSet.DeleteObject(entity); 
    }
  }
```

Controller Code

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    #region Core Action Methods

    public HomeController()
    {
        this._unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(((IObjectContextAdapter)new BookContext()).ObjectContext);
    }

  private IEnumerable<BookViewModel> GetBookdsViewModels(int id)
    {
        //THE CODE WHERE ITS NOT RETURNING THE UPDATED VLAUES
        //var query = _unitOfWork.Books.GetAll().Where(d => d.Id== id);

        //I WANT TO CHANGE THIS CODE
        ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)new BookContext()).ObjectContext;
        ObjectSet<Book> set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<Book>();
        set.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
        var query = from a in set
                    where a.Id== id && !a.IsDeleted
                    select a;

 return query
            .Select(
            c => new BookViewModel
            {
                Id = c.Id ,
                Name = c.Name
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is because you're executing things directly against your database, and then trying to refer back to the local copy that's stored in your repository and they're different.

```
public void UpdateAuthor(int id)
    {
        _context.ExecuteStoreCommand("sp_UpdateAuthor @param1", 
            new SqlParameter("param1", id));
     }
```

When you run this query, you're making a change in your db instead of your local - why dont you do something like this:

```
public void UpdateAuthor(int id)
{
  var book  = Books.GetById(id);
   /* make changes to your book object */
   _unit.Save();
}
```

If you're wanting to make changes using store procs, you're going to have to **dispose** of your context, and recreate the repo's so that you're working with data from the DB instead of the local copy.

Comment: thank you for your answer,  unfortunately i dont know how to implement you answer on my current design. Sorry Im only a beginner. I tried the var book = this.Books.GetAll(), but the book doesnt have ExecuteStoreCommand. Please guide me how to dispose and recreate my repo. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Mark Oreta's answer, you need to ensure your Model is updated after manually executing a stored proc on your database.  If you must manually call that stored proc then try this afterward:

```
_context.Entry<Book>(instanceOfAuthor).Reload();
```

Which might be:

```
_context.Entry<Book>(_context.Books.GetById(id)).Reload();
```

Comment: Thanks, why is that I dont have .Entry property?

Comment: It is because you are using ObjectContext instead of DbContext.  See this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032683/objectcontext-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-entry-and-no-extension-metho