# Entity Framework: Get parent record with filtered child records

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I don't really know much about EF but have to do some bugfixing. One of the bugs occurs as follows:

- Get parent record (EF LINQ query) using `ObjectContext`
- Change some property
- Save changes

The problem is the `Get parent record` and more specifically **getting only the active children of the parent**.

This is the current *hack*:

```
var data =
    (from q in Context.Questions.Include("Status").Include("Category")
     where q.Id == id
     select q).SingleOrDefault();

var atts = Context.Answers.Where(a => a.qId == id && a.active); // 1
data.Answers.Clear(); // 2
foreach (var att in atts)
{
    data.Answers.Add(att); // 3
}
```

What happens:

1. Fetch the active child records from the database
2. Because of lazy loading, all attachments are fetched from the database. The collection is then immidiately cleared. (EF tracking marks these records as "to delete"?)
3. Loop over all active records and add them again to the collection (EF tracking marks these records as "to insert"?)

I'm getting the following exception when updating: `The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.`

A pretty generic error which, I assume, occurs because EF is confused about clearing the collection and then having some of the same records added again.

**My question**: How do I get only the active child records and get them in an "Unchanged" state so that at no point EF can decide to delete and reinsert my records. And obviously I also don't want to lose the non-active records when updating.

**Not the answer** (or is it?): Often found on SO and Google but can't get this to work:

```
Context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

var data =
    (from q in Context.Questions.Include("Status").Include("Category")
     where q.qId == id
     select new
     {
         Question = q,
         Answers = q.Answer.Where(a => a.active)
     }).ToArray().Select(q => q.Question).FirstOrDefault();

return data; // Does not contain the answers... :(
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly load the property instead of loading it, then clearing it. This will prevent the unwanted objects from being loaded in the object graph, so you don't get the error when you disconnect the inactive entities.

```
var data =
    (from q in Context.Questions.Include("Status").Include("Category")
     where q.Id == id
     select q).SingleOrDefault();

Context.Entry(data).Collection(b => b.Answers).Query()
    .Where(a => a.active)
    .Load();
```

Comment: Unfortunately `Entry` is defined in `DbContext` which is derived from `ObjectContext` which is what is used in the project.

Comment: Try converting your ObjectContext to a DbContext.  See [objectcontext-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032683/objectcontext-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-entry-and-no-extension-metho)

Comment: Do you want to use both Include() AND Load()?  I think if you use Load() then you don't need Include().  Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: His include is a different nav property (status) then the one that's being loaded (Answers).  I just left it in there because it was in the original code sample..

Answer (score 0):

The call `data.Answers.Clear()` is not enough, cause it only removes the association between your Question and Answers. If you also want to delete those answers, you need to delete them from the Context too.

```
foreach(var answer in data.Answers) {
  Context.DeleteObject(answer);
}

data.Answers.Clear();
```

Comment: I don't want to delete anything. I want to `get` one Question and all its active Answers.

Comment: You are clearing the Answers of your Question, so that the ForeignKey of your Answers get set to NULL which is not allowed unless the property is nullable

Comment: Clearing the answers is the ugly hack responsible for the bugs. `I don't want to delete anything`. If I could achieve having the Question with the active Answers only without any deleting/clearing, that'd be fantastic.