# On wrapping ObjectContext with DbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dbcontext, objectcontext

I am using EF 6.x with MVC 4 and VS2010.

I am testing an application where I have created database model from existing database, essentially I have added `Edmx` object to the application. I am at a very early stage of testing **Generic Repository** and **Unity of Work**. I have copied / pasted a block of code with some little adjustments from the [ASP.NET website](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) but I run into a problem that `ObjectContext` does not have functions such as `Set()`, `Entry()`, `Find()` etc. I tried to follow [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032683/objectcontext-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-entry-and-no-extension-metho) and wrap `ObjectContext` in `DbContext`:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private DbContext _dbcontext;
    private StudentContext _context;
    private DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(StudentContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
        this._dbcontext = new DbContext(_context, true); // type mismatch of input parameters
        this._dbSet = _dbcontext.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    // ...
}
```

but compiler does not accept it due to wrong input parameters. `_context` is derived from `ObjectContext`. I was surprised because after reading [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220058(v=vs.113).aspx) I thought the constructor `DbContext(ObjectContext objectContext, bool dbContextOwnsObjectContext)` can create `DbContext` object if I provide `StudentContext`.

What am I missing?