# Entity Framework 6, DB first, Multiple Schemas One Model

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a DB already defined with multiple schemas, each of them has exactly the same tables and relations (we need to separate the DB depending on project to be load).
I use EF6 wizard with the option EF Designer from DB (DB First), after choosing the connection, I can choose the tables, views and so on:

[DB Schemas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ty6Z.jpg)

If I choose here only one schema with all its tables (ie: P08590) then the model contains entities that will CRUD only tables from such schema (obviously).
The thing is that I need to CRUD data from different schemas depending on logging into one project.
After reading and googling a bit I’ve found that you can tell a class through an attribute which Table and Schema it refers to:

```
[Table("P08590.ACTIVITIES")]
public partial class ACTIVITy
{
    ...
}
```

So I came up with the idea to have some kind of global variable stored after logging in the app:

```
[Table("ACTIVITIES", Schema = globalVariable)]
public partial class ACTIVITy
{
    ...
}
```

But it’s not posible to pass a variable to an attribute. Is it any possible way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Adapter on [codeplex](http://efmodeladapter.codeplex.com/) will help you to achieve this.

No doubt that you have to tweak your code a bit

To use this adapter you have to convert your context class to a partial class and inherit it from `AdaptingObjectContext` like

```
public partial class MyObjectContext : BrandonHaynes.ModelAdapter.EntityFramework.AdaptingObjectContext
{
        public MyObjectContext() 
        : base(myConnectionString, 
            new ConnectionAdapter(
                new TableSchemaModelAdapter("myschema"), 
            System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()))
        {
        ...
        }
}
```

For more information you can follow this [blog](http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2010/12/05/changing-entity-framework-model-at-runtime/)

**EDIT**

As DbContext has taken the place of ObjectContext (DbContext as a wrapper on ObjectContext), we can still use this solution to construct the DbContext and use all the feature of this component. You just have to construct the object in the way defined for this tool and then create the DbContext by using ObjectContext in Repository(or on some other place).

To Achieve this you can follow the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696505%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and the nice reply on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032683/objectcontext-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-entry-and-no-extension-metho/11032822#11032822)

Comment: Thank you very much Ashish, that's exactly what I was looking for...
Sadly I have to tell you that it's not working since the project seem abandoned, with the latest update back in 2010. As a result, it only had support for the (now considered obsolete) ObjectContext rather than DbContext. Any clue about how to adapt it?

Comment: Actually in the discussions page of the source code there's exactly the same question but I don't understand how it has been solved: [Entity Framework Runtime Model Adapter](http://efmodeladapter.codeplex.com/discussions/395564)

Comment: @JurgenHarms sorry for late reply, He is actually talking about this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696505(v=vs.103).aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/a/11032822.

Comment: @JurgenHarms As DbContext is a light weight wrapper around ObjContext with some smart methods. You can always create dbcontext from objContext or vice versa..

Comment: Thank you for replying @Ashish! I tried to pass an ObjectContext to the DBContext constructor, but it's not working since in EF6 they've changed namespaces and now it expects an System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext but from the DLL I have an System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.
I tried to re-compile source code to .Net framework 4.5 (it was compiled for .NET 3.5) but doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use data annotations, you can use fluent API...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ActivityClass1>().ToTable("Activities", schemaVariable);
}
```